# How can I reset a Dockerized Rails app for integration testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, docker, integration-testing

My (Rails and react.js) application under test depends on a primary API application to run that is in another repository.

I have this API app running in docker, and my client application can communicate with it. Usually in Rails I use something like Database Cleaner to reset my DB between tests to ensure a clean slate for each spec.

How can I make my application, from RSpec, send some reset signal to the dockerized API application (be it use database cleaner or `rake db:seed` or something analogous)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Docker API to reload the container:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/

Remember that your container with API shouldn't use volume to persist data in the host.